# Customizing modern look of SharePoint

Tags: modern-experience

SharePoint modern look is good but seems to have less options for customization.

What should be done to add custom js and css files to the site? Is there a way we could add a section to masterpage , like we could in classic look?

Could anyone share their experience of branding the modern site?

I would like to know how to add styles to Master Page not Site Page.

Thank you.

Comment: I would like to add reference to master page.

Answer (score 3):

on a modern site (team site) currently the recommended way to add JavaScript to the page would be using SPFx client app.

otherwise to modifiy a theme or create one and applying it to a modern site would require powershell.

more could be found here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites

**a few things you cant do**

> Custom master pages; more extensive branding will be supported later
>   using alternative options.
>
> Changing "modern" site to use "classic" seattle.master or oslo.master.
>   Custom page layouts; we are looking to have support for multiple
>   canvases in the future.
>
> Enabling site or site collection scoped publishing features;
>   technically, features can be currently activated, but this is not a
>   supported configuration. User custom actions / custom JavaScript;
>   there will be a more controlled way to embed JavaScript on the pages
>   through the SharePoint Framework Extensions (currently in dev
>   preview).
>
> "Modern" subsites; subsites created on "modern" team sites use the
>   "classic" experience, but you can change the user experience to be
>   similar to "modern" sites.
>
> Ability to control available subsite template options. "Classic"
>   publishing features (WCM).
>
> Activation of community feature or creation of community subsites
>   under "modern" team site.

so adding a ref in the masterpage is not possible.